# VSCode Vetur settings for <style lang="scss"> validation in .vue files

Tags: sass, vuejs2, visual-studio-code, vetur

I'm not able to get vscode to show syntax error highlighting for .vue files for `<style lang="scss">...` sections. I'm pretty sure this should work, but perhaps my settings are not correct.

```
"vetur.validation.style": true
"css.validate": true
```

When css.validate is true, it just complains about syntax errors because it thinks it's "css", not "scss". But when I turn it off, I get no syntax errors.

I have disabled every other plugin expect for Vetur.